# Is it possible to use the File System Access API to watch a file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, file-system-access-api

I am working on a chrome extension that will prompt a user for a directory and then will upload specific files from that directory to the site that the extension is active on. Ideally, this extension would automatically upload these files when they change on the user's drive. With the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API), I can setup a system where I can poll the contents of the file to see if they've changed:

```js
const handles = {
  translation:{handle:null,text:''},
  html:{handle:null,text:''},
  css:{handle:null,text:''}
};
//updateDirectory is triggered by clicking on a "select directory" button
async function updateDirectory(){
  const directoryHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
  Object.keys(handles).forEach((key)=>handles[key] = null);//Clear the preexisting handles.
  //Get the handles for the individual files/directories
  if(handles.interval){
    clearInterval(handles.interval);
  }
  for await (let handle of directoryHandle.values()){
    if(handle.kind === 'file'){
      console.log('handle.name:',handle.name);
      if(handle.name === 'translation.json'){
        handles.translation.handle = handle;
      }else if(handle.name.endsWith('.html')){
        handles.html.handle = handle;
      }else if(handle.name.endsWith('.css')){
        handles.css.handle = handle;
      }
    }
  }
  startFilePoll();
}

function startFilePoll(){
  handles.interval = setInterval(updateSheet,5000);//Check files every 5 seconds
}

async function updateSheet(){
  const filePromises = Object.entries(handles).map(async ([fileType,handle])=>{
    const file = await handle.getFile();
    const text = await file.text();
    if(text !== handles[fileType].text){
      //upload file changes
    }
  });
  await Promise.all(filePromises);
  //Do other things with the changed files.
}
```

Is there a `watch()` method buried in the API documentation that I just haven't found, or some other way for the extension to monitor the file states without needing to constantly poll.

Comment: There's no such method.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to watch files *now*, but there's a proposal for [file change events](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jYXOZGen4z7kNrKnwBk5z4tbGRmGXmQ9nmoyJRm-V9M/edit#heading=h.7nki9mck5t64) which will allow you to do that in the future.